# How to recover from accidently diskpart'ing an OS X drive, destroying everything?

Tags: macos, windows, restore, data-recovery, disk-format

Ok, so, I just got my Mac back after 5 months in the repair shop. I went to install winblows 7 via Boot Camp Assistant, but was having issues. I went into diskpart, and not remembering how to use it, accidently formatted the OS X drive. Not knowing what I had just done, I went and cleaned it. It wasn't until a few formats and conversions later that I realized I had obliterated every last one of my files and critical system stuff, including my recovery drive, because I had selected the wrong volume to change.

I have no doubt there is no way to get my files back, but I at least want OS X back. I have no access to any other Mac anywhere, and I can't afford to pay for support or a new image, and somehow every last Time Machine backup is corrupt.

What can or should I do?

EDIT: As per request, I ran `clean` `format` `convert` `delete` `recover` and `create` in diskpart. The external drive was not empty, but is now :/

MacBook Pro,
Model A1502,
Mfd. late 2014,
11" model,
128GB Internal SSD,
1TB external HDD,
x64 Architecture

Comment: Depending on what you exactly did there might be a chance to recover your files. Which commands did you enter in diskpart? What does "..I went and cleaned it.." mean? Which kind of formats and conversions did you conduct? Is the 1 TB external drive empty? Please add the answers to your question!

Comment: Eh! Sorry, didn't get notified.. `clean` `format` `convert` `delete` `recover` and `create`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to a standard wireless WPA/WPA2 network, it should be possible to reinstall OS X from an internet connection. Try booting with 
`⌘-Option-R` held down as soon as you power on. Do not let go until the Apple logo is visible on screen.

Per [this Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314):

> Newer Macs include the ability to start up directly from an Internet-based version OS X Recovery. Your Mac automatically uses this feature when the Recovery System on the startup drive isn't available. For example, if your startup drive encounters an issue, or if your startup drive has been replaced or erased. Internet Recovery lets you start your Mac directly from Apple's servers.

I would not attempt to do this until you have exhausted any options you wish to take for data recovery.

Comment: `I had obliterated every last one of my files and critical system stuff, including my recovery drive` -- OP

Comment: @Thecheater887 The presence of a recovery drive should have no bearing on your MacBook Pro's ability to do an Internet recovery. [Here's an example of a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0K82njigCTA) where someone had installed a brand new hard drive in their MacBook Pro. This should be entirely in your logic board's firmware.

Comment: Well, all I know is that the `Command+R` wont work, so have you got any other ideas?

Comment: @Thecheater887 The article I linked earlier wasn't clear on this, but a quick search on my end is suggesting you need to hold down another key for an Internet recovery session. Hold down `⌘+Option+R` starting as soon as you hear the boot chime when you turn it on. Do not let go until you see the Apple logo.

Comment: I'm not hearing a boot chime. I'm just getting a lit, but black screen. And it just sits there, chilling. Could I have screwed up the EFI by any mistake?

Comment: @Thecheater887 Maybe your PRAM got messed up? Try resetting it with `⌘+Option+P+R`. Hold it down as soon as you power on.